# Free pdf reader with typewriter capability

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

Is there any free pdf reader with a typewriter capability like the one provided by acrobat reader professional as in the below image (or in the link http://users.wfu.edu/yipcw/atg/pdf/705typewriter/images/acrobat705-typewriter-annot.gif?

[image]

To be more specific, I would like to insert any text at any place (regardless of if there is a textbox there or not, even at the margins) of a page of the pdf file. (Not to confuse with comments.) Preferably, in the typewriter, one can choose specific size and specific fonts.

Comment: What features do you want it to have in addition to the image? Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Your image is from ancient times Acrobat Pro... Nowadays I think [**Free Acrobat Reader**](https://get.adobe.com/reader/) can do the same (although it is called comments, it is just like the typewriter.)

See here in action:
[image]

If you want something with a bit more options of formatting etc. You can take a look at [**Foxit Reader**](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) which has a Typewriter option:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [Sejda's Online PDF Editor](https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor)

1. Open https://www.sejda.com/pdf-editor and upload your file
2. Select the text tool (active by default)
3. Click on the page and add new text
4. Click on existing page text to change it
5. When you're ready click Apply Changes and then Download to save the edited file back to your computer

Here's a small screen cast of this tool in action:

[image: How to edit text using Sejda's PDF editor]

The online PDF Editor is free to use for files up to 50Mb and one can save 3 times an hour for free.

There's a [desktop version of the PDF editor](https://www.sejda.com/desktop) as well, if you'd rather edit your files offline.

I'm one of the developers, I hope our software helps you.